# Enabling control-c and control-v copy and paste in Emacs

Tags: emacs, keyboard-shortcuts

How do I copy & paste in Emacs with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>c</kbd> and <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>v</kbd>?
What must I add to my .emacs file?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Check out the [Cua Mode](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode).

Answer (score 1):

Old question, but nevertheless.

Unbind Ctrl+C because it's modifier in Emacs:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'undefined)`

Bind Ctrl+C to Copy:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-c") 'kill-ring-save)`

Bind Ctrl+V to Paste:

`(global-set-key (kbd "C-v") 'yank)`