# Customize emacs to support ctrl+c,v,x and replace text region etc

Tags: emacs

I used to have emacs set up the way I liked it until I lost my emacs configuration file.

How do I customize emacs so that it supports CTRL+x,c,v keys as in windows (cut, copy paste)
and also when you paste, the highlighted region is replaced?

I'd also like the delete key to behave so that if a region is highlighted it will delete the region.  It currently just deletes the character to the right cursor.

Comment: I use C-c and C-x as prefix characters for almost everything I do in emacs.  It's unclear to me how one would use emacs if these keys meant something else.

Comment: CUA-Mode use of C-c and C-x is only active when a region is selected. It's actually a lot less intrusive than you may imagine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [enabling control c and control v copy and paste in emacs](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097890/enabling-control-c-and-control-v-copy-and-paste-in-emacs)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use CUA mode for CTRL+x,c,v. - http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/CuaMode

Write in your .emacs:

```
(cua-mode t)
    (setq cua-auto-tabify-rectangles nil) ;; Don't tabify after rectangle commands
    (transient-mark-mode 1)               ;; No region when it is not highlighted
    (setq cua-keep-region-after-copy t)
```

If you use Emacs 23.1 and higher, cua exists by default in emacs.

Comment: @Matt-H CUA mode also has an excellent rectangle helper mode. Ctrl+RET to activate it.